# do_shortcode doesn't work on some pages

Tags: shortcode

Im using Artiss Currency Converter to convert some numbers on my website. Im trying to out put `do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="aud" to="jpy"]')` in 2 pages. One is a template page in `mythemefolder/newtemplate.php` and the other is in `mythemefolder/functions/single_product.php`

`do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="aud" to="jpy"]')` works Perfect in `newtempalte.php` but it doesn't seem to work in `single_product.php`.

Why is that? How can I fix it and does it matter where the php file is for `do_shortcode` to work?

This is the funciton in single_product.php

```
    function cps_ajax_search($meta_boxes){
    $posts = cps_search_posts();?>

<?php get_template_part("sidebar-left-common");?>

<?php require_once(TEMPLATEPATH."/functions/var/default-box-one.php"); ?>
<div class="detail-page-content hideOnSearch">

 <!-- detail page content starts -->

<div class="searchBreadcrumbs"><!--  breadcrumbs starts -->
        <?php  '<a href="#" class="cpsBack">Home</a> &raquo;';?> 
        <?php cps_breadcrumbs(); ?>
    </div> <!-- breadcrumbs ends -->
    <div style="clear:both"></div>  
<div class="sort-by-bar"> <!-- sort bar starts -->
<div class="searchSort"> <!-- search sort starts -->
<?php _e('Sort By:','language');?>
<?php cps_sort_by('miles') ?> - 
<?php cps_sort_by('year') ?> -
<?php cps_sort_by('price') ?>

</div> <!-- search sort ends -->
</div> <!-- sort bar ends -->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
        <?php
            $displayed = array();
             if(!empty($posts)): foreach($posts as $post): 

                if(in_array($post->ID,$displayed)):
                    continue;
                else:
                    $displayed[] = $post->ID;
                endif;
            ?>
<?php global $options;$fields;$options2;$options3;$symbols;
              $fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod1', true);
              $options2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod2', true);
              $options3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod3', true);
              $symbols = get_option('gorilla_symbols');
              $options = get_option('gorilla_fields'); ?>           
<?php $blogurl = get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
<?php $surl = get_bloginfo('url'); ?>   
<div class="result-car"><!-- result car -->
<?php       
    $args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => 1,
    );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {


        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        echo '<a href='.$surl.'/'.$post->post_name.'>'.wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail_results').'<span class="'.$fields['statustag'].'"></span></a>';
    }
} ?> 
                        <div class="result-detail-wrapper">  <!-- result detail wrapper -->
                            <p><a href="<?php echo $post->post_name ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $post->post_title ?>"><?php if ( $fields['year']){ echo $fields['year'];}else {  echo ''; }?> <?php echo $post->post_title ?></a></p>
                            <p><strong><?php if (isset( $fields['miles'])){
                            ##### New ##########
                            //number_format($fields['miles'],0,'.','.')
                            echo number_format($fields['miles'],0,'.',',').' '.$options['milestext'];
                            ##### End ##########
                            }else {  echo ''; };?></strong></p>
                            <p><?php if (isset( $fields['vehicletype'])){ echo $fields['vehicletype'].' | ';}else {  echo ''; };?> <?php if (isset( $fields['transmission'])){ echo $fields['transmission'];}else {  echo ''; };?><br/><?php if (isset( $options2['cylinders'])){ echo $options2['cylinders'].' '.$options['cylinderstext'].' | ';}else {  echo ''; };?><?php if (isset( $fields['interior'])){ echo $fields['interior'].' | ';}else {  echo ''; };?><?php if (isset( $fields['epamileage'])){ echo $fields['epamileage'];}else {  echo ''; };?></p>
                            <p class="result-price"><?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/functions/var/default-box-one.php");
                            //echo $symbols['currency'];     
                            ##### New ##########
                            // echo number_format($fields['price']);  
                            ##### End ##########

                          ?>

                          <span id="calPriceInAud<?php echo $callPriceInAudCounter; ?>">Calculating...</span>

                            <script>
                            //Calculator.js
                            //function CarCostCalculator(enteredPriceInYen,cubicMeters,complianceFee,serviceFee,inventoryItemID)
                            CarCostCalculator(<?php echo $fields['price']; ?>,14, 2500, 1100,<?php  echo do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="usd" to="aud"]');?>)
                            </script>
                             </p>

                         </div> <!--   result detail wrapper ends -->
 </div> <!-- result car ends --> 
            <?php endforeach; else: ?>
                <p style="padding:30px;"><?php _e('Sorry, no listings matched your criteria.','language');?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="bottom-pagination"> <!-- Pagination starts -->
                        <p><a id="link" href="#top"><?php _e('BACK TO TOP','language');?></a></p>
                        <p class="paging">
                            <?php cps_show_pagination() ?>
                        </p>
                  </div>  <!-- Pagination ends -->  
                </div>
    <?php

    exit;
}
```

As you can see

CarCostCalculator(`<?php echo $fields['price']; ?>`,14, 2500, 1100,`<?php  echo do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="usd" to="aud"]');?>`)

has `do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="usd" to="aud"]')` but it doesnt work. But works fine on the template file.

Comment: I can't tell the problem based on the information provided. Please post the code that doesn't work, for starters. Post the code in context-- that is, all of the relevant code. That probably means the whole function.

Comment: You should indent correctly. You have no excuses for poor formatting other than pure lazyness, and a desire for accidental bugs. Your editor should have auto-indenting. Also you're using post meta, but nowhere have you checked if the meta actually existed, you just 'assume' it does.

Comment: @TomJNowell : Thanks. This code wasnt coded by me, its a plugin I bought, so Im not quite sure how post mata works. Im just wondering hwo to get `do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="usd" to="aud"]')` to work?

Comment: If you bought this plugin what did the people who you bought it off say when you went to them to ask for support? If you came here first instead can I ask why you did so instead of going to the people best able to answer your question?

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of the short code, it's going to be difficult if not impossible to diagnose what the issue is without spending money on the problem ( which is quite a lot to ask of people helping out in their spare time for free )

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry I understand. This is my first question and im new to wp stackexchange. Whats the best way to show the implementation of the short code you rekon?

Comment: Your answer/solution is essentially what I said about skipping the middleman, showing the implementation would have meant showing the code

Answer (score 2):

```
global $options;$fields;$options2;$options3;$symbols;
```

That is the same as:

```
global $options;
$fields;
$options2;
$options3;
$symbols;
```

You've declared options as a global, but the other variables are just stated, they're doing nothing, those lines might as well not be there.

Next we have:

```
$fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mod1', true);
```

But you're not checking if it's an error value.

```
if (isset( $fields['miles'])){
                            ##### New ##########
                            //number_format($fields['miles'],0,'.','.')
                            echo number_format($fields['miles'],0,'.',',').' '.$options['milestext'];
                            ##### End ##########
                            }else {  echo ''; }
```

So the reason you are getting nothing, is because the miles field is not set. So it prints '', aka nothing. Try replacing the '' with 'error' and you'll see 'error' printed.

Also finally, short codes are intended for content. Instead you're calling the short code indirectly, and outside of the loop.

The short code may make references to the current post, and you would be better off calling the actual function the short code is bound to instead of using do_shortcode

Comment: Thanks for writing. Actually Im trying to edit an extension I bought for WP. So not quite sure whats going on in there. The `$fields['miles']` outputs values fine. The problem I have is the other plugin I installed `Artiss Currency Converter` doenst output `do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="usd" to="aud"]')`

Comment: But by your own admission it doesn't, look at your question, see where you said"CarCostCalculator(,14, 2500, 1100,)"? Notice the comma where the first value is missing?

Comment: Sorry, the editor has stripped out the <?php echo do_shortcode('[convert number=1 from="usd" to="aud"]');?> part from the question, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why some pages don't allow do_shortcode. This can apply to ANY Wordpress plugin so any one can use this trick. I included the plugin's functions php file

```
<?php require_once($dir = ABSPATH . "/wp-content/plugins/artiss-currency-converter/includes/acc-functions.php"); ?>
```

and used its function to calculate the rates

```
get_conversion( 'number=1&from=aud&to=jpy' )
```

That's it.